# Dificuldade em listar resultado SQLite em ListView Android

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, listview, xamarin.android

Estou criando uma aplicação para treinar desenvolvimento mobile, estou fazendo para Android no Visual Studio, usando o Xamarin. Estou com dificuldade de listar um resultado do SQLite.

Criei duas activity, uma para fazer o cadastro e já listar, e o outro apenas para listar os dados cadastrados em uma ListView. O problema é, na primeira activity, ao inserir um dado, ele lista os outros(que já existem no banco) normalmente, porém na segunda activity, ao carregar o app, ele lança uma exceção: 
"Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ocorreu". A exceção se encontra no seguinte treco de código:

```
lista.Adapter = adapter;
```

Segue os códigos:

Função que trás os resultados:

```
public List<Abastece> GetAbastecimentos()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conexao = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(pasta, "Abastece.db")))
            {
                return conexao.Table<Abastece>().ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Código em C#:

```
namespace Control_Car
{
[Activity(Label = "ListaAbast", MainLauncher = true)]
public class ListaAbast : Activity
{
    Button button;
    ListView lista;
    DataBase db;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CriarBancoDeDados();
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.bt_registrar);
        lista = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.lista);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListaAbast);

        var listaAbast = db.GetAbastecimentos();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Abastece>(this, 
        Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, listaAbast);
        lista.Adapter = adapter;
        lista.Activated = true;
    }

    private void CriarBancoDeDados()
    {
        db = new DataBase();
        db.CriarBanco();
    }
}
}
```

Apenas reforçando, esse código em C# está nas duas activity, porém se eu tento chamar a função de preencher a ListView no OnCreate ele lança a exceção. Para exemplificar vou colocar o código da outra activity, em que eu quero que só lista os dados ao inserir algum outro:

```
namespace Control_Car
{
[Activity(Label = "Abastecer", ScreenOrientation = 
ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class Abastecer : Activity
{
    Button btn;
    EditText valorKM, preco, litros, nomePosto;
    ListView ltAbastecimento;
    DataBase db;
    string[] items = { };
    List<Abastece> listaAbast = new List<Abastece>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CriarBancoDeDados();


        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Abastecer);

        btn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.bt_registrar);
        valorKM = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.valor_km);
        preco = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.valor_preco);
        litros = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.valor_litros);
        nomePosto = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.nome_posto);
        ltAbastecimento = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.lista);
        CarregaDados();

        btn.Click += delegate
        {
            Abastece abastece = new Abastece()
            {
                ValorKM = Double.Parse(valorKM.Text),
                Preco = Double.Parse(preco.Text),
                Litros_qnt = Double.Parse(litros.Text),
                PostoUt = nomePosto.Text
            };
            db.InserirAbastecimento(abastece);
            CarregaDados();
        };
    }

    private void CarregaDados()
    {
        listaAbast = db.GetAbastecimentos();
        ArrayAdapter<Abastece> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Abastece>(this, 
    Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, listaAbast);
        ltAbastecimento.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void CriarBancoDeDados()
    {
        db = new DataBase();
        db.CriarBanco();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Já tentou dar um breakpoint no modo debug na linha `lista.Adapter = adapter` e ver se a variável adapter está nula? Essa exceção é mandada quando você tenta usar uma variável que tem valor nulo